# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'load_data'

Tags: python

So I have a multi-task deep learning code that takes omniglot (handwritten alphabet letters) images from files of different languages and labels them with their folder names than prepares them for training. The original code is part of a homework given at the Stanford CS330 course (pdf [here](https://cs330.stanford.edu/material/homework_1_updated.pdf) and zip file [here](https://cs330.stanford.edu/material/hw1_updated.zip)). The code is in two files load_data.py and hw1.py. It's pretty straight forward you load the data and label it and then run the training code. I get the following error when running the code in the notebook. How do I load the data from my computer using the notebook and then run the hw1 file? Note: In case you are wondering I am not a Stanford student nor am I taking this course nor am I doing this for someone else taking the course. Your help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import tensorflow as tf
  3 from load_data import DataGenerator
  4 from tensorflow.python.platform import flags
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'load_data' `

Comment: Are you sure `hw1.py` is in the same directory as `load_data.py`?

Comment: Yes they are. But I am running this on the notebook (so using the browser) so it should not make a difference. Anyway I launched Spyder and ran the code through there an got the following error `line 13, in del_all_flags
    flags_dict = FLAGS._flags()

AttributeError: type object 'Flag' has no attribute '_flags'`.  I tried using this `tf.compat.v1.flags.Flag` but still got the same error. What do you guys think and thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Try `import load_data` and then just call `DataGenerator` using `load_data.DataGenerator`.

Comment: Thank you very much @ZWang for your effort. So I tried running it from Spyder and hence I dont seem to have the same problem. However, I have this error istead `in del_all_flags
    flags_dict = FLAGS._flags()

AttributeError: type object 'Flag' has no attribute '_flags'` Please note that I tried solving this error by using `tf.compat.v1.flags.Flag` and `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and  `tf.disable_v2_behavior() ` to avoid any tensorflow 2.0 related behavior. Still does not seem to solve the issue. If anyone has taken this course or made a github repository of it that would great.

Comment: Post your tensorflow, python, cuda versions